# Error with using join "is not sorted" using files previously sorted (Ubuntu termina and Gawkl)

Tags: sorting, join, terminal, gawk

I have this tabulated document with over 60,000 registers:

```
head -2 hg38.txt 

717 NM_000525   chr11   -   17385248    17388659    17386918    17388091    117385248,  17388659,   0   KCNJ11  cmpl    cmpl    0,
987 NM_000242   chr10   -   52765379    52771700    52768136    52771635    452765379,52769246,52770669,52771448,   52768510,52769315,52770786,52771700,    0   MBL2    cmpl    cmpl    1,1,1,0,
```

Previously, I extracted from it, som selected lines of the third column, and save it in another chromosomes.txt file

```
gawk '{print $3}' hg38.txt | sort -u | grep -v "_" | sort -o chromosomes.txt
head -5 chromosomes.txt 
chr1
chr10
chr11
chr12
chr13
```

And now, I want to select those register which have the same field for "chromosomes", but since I want also another field in my end result, I do this:

```
gawk '{print $3, $13}' hg38.txt | sort | join - chromosomes.txt > final.txt
```

But the join command warns that:

```
join: -:833: is not sorted: chr10 GLRX3
```

How can I join them? Could also, after joining them, instead of creating a temp file, do more stuff by just adding |? For example:

```
gawk '{print $3, $13}' hg38.txt | sort | join - chromosomes.txt | gawk '{print $2}' | uniq -c | gawk 'BEGIN{t=0}{t=t+$1} END{print t/NR}'
```

Thank you for you answers in advance!

Comment: isn't this going to give you the original file records? By definition all records in chromosomes.txt exist in hg38.txt.  What do you want to achieve?perhaps there is an easier alternative.

Comment: I am not expecting the same result. By creating the chromosomes.txt, since I only grep those registers which don't have _ in the third field, I create a template than then I use, together with join, for removing those lines that have _ in the third field (again). Sorry If I am not clear, but it is complicated for me as well :S

Comment: so you just want to filter the records where third field is "_"?  just use `awk '$3!="_"{print $3,$13}' file`  no need for the joins.  You can sort the output as needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot karakfa, It didn't come into my mind such a idea. I am just a beginner and I hope I won't need help in the future for these basic things!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not doing the filtering in gawk as well?

```
gawk '{ if (!match($3,"_")) {print $3, $13} }' hg38.txt
```

Comment: or more idiomatic `$3!~/_/{print ..`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do not have expertise in using bash or gawk. I studied a biotechnology degree and now I am doing a master in bioinformatics for a few weeks. So, I haven't been taught in too many commands. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi again. Now I am realizing that match doesn't work like grep. Actually, I do not want to get those that match with _, but which contains _. In other words, some registers in the third value look like chr12 and others chr12_XXXXX. So, I do want to grep, and not to match. Thanks a lot anyway! :D

Comment: I think this should work instead of the "_" part: "(.*)_(.*)"

Comment: Esteve & Attila - you both misunderstand awk's match() function and regexp comparisons in general. `grep "_"` == `awk 'match($0,/_/)'` == `grep ".*_.*"` == `awk 'match($0,/(.*)_(.*)/'` etc. See @karakfa's comment and get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.